# Yii Assets Manager: Write access is overwritten after each pass

Tags: php, yii, assets

I'm having trouble with Yii's Asset Mananger. I've built several widgets for my app that try to write to the folder. Same issue when the framework tries to write it it. On each pass it I get a copy denied error. Then I set the folder path back to 0777, it works and so on...

I'm not sure why this is happening. Is this enough info for an accurate answer?

Comment: os? webserver? full path to assets folder? what are those?

Comment: OS: Mac OSX 10.6, Webserver: nginx, Path: trunk/htdocs/assets/

Answer (score 1):

You have to give write access for apache to the assets folder.

Comment: For sure. I've done that. So if I have five files that need in the assets folder I need to give it write access ten times. Once for each folder creation and one for each files creation. Wondering why it won't persist

Comment: On my system, I first delete the assets folder and give 777 to the parent folder. Then use mkdir() to create the assets folder. Remove 777 on the parent folder. The correct settings are persisted on assets.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I use Yii for some time now and the only instances where I tried to write to the Assets Folder was right in the beginning when I didn't know how it worked...

Perhaps you should do whatever changes you need **before** you publish the assets. I think that would solve your problem.

Other than that, I think you could `chown` the assets folder to `www-data` or whatever other username **apache** uses (that's if you're using **mod_php**). If you don't know whether or not you're using **mod_php**, you probably **are** using it.